# How can I access a site before I click confirmation link in the verification email?

Tags: site-verification, email-accounts

Recently (maybe during last year) I noticed many Web apps that give the user access to the dashboard *before* the user clicks the confirmation link in the verification email they send to the user.

I wonder, what is this trend?

It *looks like* that access to the dashboard is not limited even before I click the confirmation link. Is it an illusion? Why then the confirmation email at all?

Note that I ask about the trend encompassing a big percent of sites of the Web, not about single cases of mis-programmed sites.

Comment: Yet you failed to provide the names of websites encompassing "big percentager of website" this trend.

Comment: @davidgo Yes, I failed to write down such sites when I met them. Sorry, I can't reproduce this by memory.